# Error 1004 when referencing specific cells within a defined range

Tags: excel, vba

Edited to add solution: I was trying to do `Sumproduct` and I'm a big dummy haha

I'm trying to do a pretty simple calculation in VBA where I need to loop through two ranges and multiply specific cells then add the value to a placeholder value.

The code is:

```
Dim Input_Cas As Range
    Set Input_Cas = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A2:A51")
Dim Input_Conc As Range
    Set Input_Conc = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2:C51")
    i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("Input_Cas")(i)) = True
    Tkm = Tkm + Range("Input_Tki")(i) * (Range("Input_Conc")(i) / 100)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Mix_Tkm = Tkm
```

- The Ranges defined as *Input_Conc, Input_Tki, Input_Cas* are all in the active sheet and `Dim`/`Set` in code above this block.
- *Tkm* is double and *Mix_Tkm* is a `Dim`/`Set` range as well.
- The Error 1004 kicks out in the first line of the `Do Until ... Loop`.

Since the syntax doesn't *seem* to be causing any issues in the `IsEmpty(Range("Input_Cas")(i)) = True` I'm not sure why that same syntax doesn't work below it. All cells referenced contain numerical values as well, just in case that is relevant.

I love you wonderful people and thanks for your help in advance.

Edit: The `Dim/Set` for the ranges are

```
Dim Input_Cas As Range
        Set Input_Cas = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A2:A51")
Dim Input_Conc As Range
        Set Input_Conc = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2:C51")
Dim Input_Tki As Range
        Set Input_Tki = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("G2:G51")
```

Comment: Please show the  "DIm/Set in code above this block" - `Range("Input_Cas")` would be appropriate for a *named* range, not a range variable.

Comment: Are you recreating `SUMPRODUCT` btw?

Comment: if the ranges are variables set earlier in the code, then they are either ranges or strings holding addresses.  If range objects: `Input_Cas(i)` is all you need, if string addresses remove the `""`: `Range(Input_Cas)(i)`

Comment: @bigben I didn't even know that `Sumproduct` was a thing. Dang I think that's what I want to do haha. I added the dim/set as an edit to my question

Comment: Yeah you just need `Input_Cas(i)` and similar... but just use SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @BigBen you sir a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to self-answer instead of your latest edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I am posting the answer to self for folks from the future.

I was attempting to recreate the `Sumproduct` function from excel within VBA by making a loop. What I was attempting was more effectively done in excel. I didn't know `Sumproduct` was a thing and it does exactly what I was attempting.

Thanks to Bigben for providing the solution I couldn't find for myself.